# Using const and decltype with a pointer variable

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code allows me to change the value at *p2 even though p2 is declared with const.

```
int *p1;

const decltype(p1) p2 = new int(100);
*p2 = 200;
cout << "*p2: " << *p2 << endl; // Outputs *p2: 200
```

However, if I use "int *" instead of "decltype(p1)", then the compiler flags an error.

```
const int * p2 = new int(100);
*p2 = 200;
cout << "*p2: " << *p2 << endl;

error: assignment of read-only location ‘* p2’
  *p2 = 200;
      ^
```

I am using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2.

Does decltype ignore const specifier when applied on pointer variable?

Answer (score 10):

`const decltype(p1) p2` means `int* const p2` .

This means that you cannot change `p2`, but you may change the things being pointed to.

---

`const T` always applies const to the so-called "top level" of `T`. When `T` is a composite type (that is, a type built up from the basic set of types) then you will have to jump through hoops if you want to apply `const` to the lower levels.

When T is `int *` , adding top level const would give `int * const`. The `*` demarcates a level; to get at the stuff below the `*` you have to manually remove the `*`, apply `const`, then put the `*` back.

A possible solution is:

```
const std::remove_pointer<decltype(p1)>::type *p2 = new int(100);
```

Comment: @quantdev you're right, I copied from another SO answer without testing. Is there another solution?

Comment: @quantdev There is `const std::remove_reference<decltype(*p1)>::type *p2 = ...;` although that is somewhat ugly

Comment: `std::add_pointer<std::add_const<std::remove_pointer<decltype(p1)>::type>::type>::type p2 = new int(100);` would work...

Comment: @quantdev I've come up with a hybrid... probably unnecessary to use `add_pointer` and `add_const` here

Answer (score 5):

[`std::pointer_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits) would come in handy here. `std::pointer_traits::element_type` and `std::pointer_traits::rebind` allow you to write a generic expression which will work well for any pointer-like type:

```
using element_type = std::pointer_traits<decltype(p1)>::element_type;
using pointer_like_to_const = std::pointer_traits<decltype(p1)>::rebind<std::add_const_t<element_type>>;
pointer_like_to_const p2 = new int(100);
```

Note that this code would work even if `p1` was `shared_ptr<int>` or `unique_ptr<int>`.